# data analysis on sliced indexes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, analysis

How do I find the returns_per_month, and annualized_return from this set of data I had sliced from an index?

Here below I have a copy of the kind of equation I am trying to execute with; returns.loc["1999":"2015"]

equation:
n_months = returns.shape[0]
returns_per_month = (returns+1).prod()**(1/n_months) - 1
returns_per_month

Lo 20    0.011860
Hi 20    0.007859
dtype: float64

How do I integrate returns.loc["1999":"2015"] into this equation?

I have tried
nmonths = returns.loc["1999":"2015"]
returns_per_month = (nmonths+1).prod()**(1/returns.loc["1999":"2015"]) - 1
returns_per_month

although I get an answer in a different format from the previous one.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2COb.png)

Comment: Nicolai, Please share with us more information such as what you have came up with or what is the main dataframe.

Comment: What those columns `Hi 20` and `Low 20` means? What concept/formula of **return** do you want to use? You really did not provided enough information.

Comment: Hi 20 and Low 20 are a set of columns I had extracted from the full index. My intention is to find the annualized_return and returns_per_month answers of this subset of data.